# It is possible first byte to be zero when reading a file?

Tags: java, io

[image]

It is possible first byte to be zero when reading a file?

Comment: Why do you doubt that? What makes you think that it can *not* be 0?

Comment: Juat want to be sure.

Comment: But something must have made you think that there might be such a very specific restriction specifically on the very first byte of a file. I'm just asking because that something might also hide some mis-conceptions. If we could get to the root of that thought, we can maybe help you understand something else better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, absolutely.

Each individual byte in a file can have any value that a byte can hold. `0` has no special meaning here (nor does any other value).